# SUMIF by month different entry locations

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Beforehand please check my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gIN3Xvg59B8awxjhjjH6GxMMCY_wrvh8v6uQMVlzj68/edit?usp=sharing).

I'm trying to use `SUMIF` or any specific formula that shows the total amount of income of each month over on the side (March, April, May...)

As noticed the date (month) is not always the same on each column (Date 1, Date 2, Date 3...), it may vary.

I've tried `SUMIF`, `FILTER`, `ARRAYFORMULA`, but haven't had any luck.

Is there any way to do this or do I have to change the whole structure?

Comment: so basically you want to dissect it per each month and sum it up right?

Comment: Yes. Basically sum all the amounts from **Payments** - range or columns (E:E, G:G, I:I, K:K M:M, O:O) that match the month MARCH looked up on each of the colums of **Dates** (F:F, H:H, J:J, L:L, N:N, P:P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(TEXT($F$2:$P$5,"mmmmyyyy"),S$1&"2018",$E$2:$O$5))
```

Drag to right.

SUM E2:O5,IF F2:P5 has S1's Month&2018.

Comment: Wow. This actually worked! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert a date to a number and find out the range of the month in numbers.

March starts with the end of 28th Feb, and ends with the start of 1st Apr, therefore:

- **02/28/2018** converted to a number is **43159**
- **04/01/2018** converted to a number is **43191**
- so now we know that we need to filter out stuff between **43159** **-** **43191** and sum it

**TOTAL PER ROW PER MONTH:**

(paste it into cell **S2** and drag it down)

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIFS(F2 < 43159, F2 > 43191),SUM(E2,
     IF(COUNTIFS(H2 < 43159, H2 > 43191),SUM(G2,
     IF(COUNTIFS(J2 < 43159, J2 > 43191),SUM(I2,
     IF(COUNTIFS(L2 < 43159, L2 > 43191),SUM(K2,
     IF(COUNTIFS(N2 < 43159, N2 > 43191),SUM(M2,
     IF(COUNTIFS(P2 < 43159, P2 > 43191),SUM(O2)))))))))))))
```

**TOTAL PER ALL ROWS PER MONTH:**

(paste it into cell **S2**)

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER((E2:E5),MONTH(F2:F5)=3),),
     IFERROR(FILTER((G2:G5),MONTH(H2:H5)=3),),
     IFERROR(FILTER((I2:I5),MONTH(J2:J5)=3),),
     IFERROR(FILTER((K2:K5),MONTH(L2:L5)=3),),
     IFERROR(FILTER((M2:M5),MONTH(N2:N5)=3),),
     IFERROR(FILTER((O2:O5),MONTH(P2:P5)=3),))
```

[image]

Comment: I applied it to the main document and it's giving me a number that's not correct. I did however try =SUM(FILTER((E2:E5),MONTH(F2:F5)=3)) and was giving me the correct one, however I cannot deploy MONTH to take into account other columns.

Comment: @A.C. fixed. try now

Comment: Still gave me an error on the main document.

Comment: @A.C. cant be. see yourself: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dYArWHY9zEMQrOgOI7VHfAy6OrUmjW5qvcqTZCUgNTg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it! It also worked. Appreciate it! :)